# is a normed space is always closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am reading optimization by vector space methods written by Luenberger.

And there is the following sentence:

A normed space is always closed but not necessarily complete.

I am wondering why a normed space is always closed.

I know if you see in topological perspective, the entire set is always closed/open but in this book, the closed set is defined as a complement to open set and open set is defined when the interior of the set is actually itself.

I am asking why a normed space is closed in the above definition of closed and open set.

Comment: You are asking if a normed space $X$ is closed, meaning that its complement is open. But what is its complement? What is the "ambient space"? Anyway, yours is the usual definition of closed. But for the whole space, the complement is just the empty set, which is open.